# what's the result of dividing the max value by min value and then minus 1

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, data-analysis

we have the following dataset this is just a sample

```
30  59.000000
63  75.873721
64  74.619113
```

the max value is 75.873721 and the min value is  59.

the question was

> How much heavier the age group with the highest average weight than the age group with the lowest weight?

i used the percentage difference but the analyst used

```
avg_weight_by_age.max() / avg_weight_by_age.min() - 1
```

what's this result? and what's its name in statistics?

note: it was MCQ and his answer is in choices unlike mine
I know it might be a silly question but I'm still learning
thanks in advance

i tried to calculate the difference percentage but it was wrong and i searched on google to know what's called in statistics but I got nothing

Comment: What are the "percentage difference" and "difference percentage" you used/tried?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question but for https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: How could you call this anything other than the "percentage difference"?  The max group is 28% heavier than the min group.  The fact that it is min and max is irrelevant to the operation -- it's just the percentage difference between two values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple math.

"*How much heavier the age group with the highest average weight than the age group with the lowest weight?*"

So you want the difference between the max and min, in percentage of the min:

```
(MAX - MIN)/MIN
```

which is equivalent to

```
MAX/MIN - MIN/MIN
```

Or:

```
MAX/MIN - 1
```